# Using OpenCV in Eclipse (getting started)

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, opencv

I want to use OpenCV in Eclipse Neon for C++. Unfortunately, there are some linking errors while building the project.

I followed [this](http://share-thevision.blogspot.de/2013/02/opencveclipse-on-windows.html) tutorial and passed following steps:

- Installing Eclipse Neon for C/C++ (Windows 64-bit) http ://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/neon1a
- Installing MinGW (mingw-get-setup.exe, https ://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/) in the folder C:\MinGW
- Installing OpenCV 3.1 for Windows (http ://opencv.org/downloads.html) in the folder C:\opencv
- Creating a new and empty C++ project in eclipse
- Adding the includes and libaries like described in the tutorial
- Adding a source file Test.cpp which does not gives any errors

```cpp
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      Mat im = imread(argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "lenna.png", 1);
      if (im.empty())
      {
        cout << "Cannot open image!" << endl;
        return -1;
      }
      imshow("image", im);
      waitKey(0);
      return 0;
    }
```

- Building the project

Building the project returns following errors:

```
19:00:45 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project OpenCV ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\opencv\\build\\include" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Test.o "..\\Test.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc12\\lib" "-LC:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc14\\lib" -o OpenCV.exe Test.o -lopencv_world310 
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc[__ZN2cv6StringC1EPKc]+0x2d): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x6d): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4f): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x56): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc7): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd3): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x134): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
Test.o:Test.cpp:(.text.startup+0x161): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

19:00:45 Build Finished (took 781ms)
```

Where can be the error?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Follow the tutorial more closely. -lopencv_world310 links in exactly one library. It is not one of the 4 libraries included by the tutorial.

Comment: The version 3.1 of OpenCV only contains this one libary. I also tried the version 2.4.13 and included all this 4 libaries, but I got the same error messages.

Comment: Rats. Stupid programmers always changing things.

Comment: Is it so wrong to try a newer version? The origin version of the tutorial does not exist any more and the version 2.4.13 with similar libaries to the tutorial causes the same problems. I think that the error is elsewhere...

Comment: That was an attempt at being funny. I am myself a stupid programmer. It is definitely linker related. You definitely have a opencv_world310 or you would be getting a different error. Order of linked objects looks right. I'd expect an error message if mingw is compiling 32 bit against a 64 bit library. I join you in puzzlement. What you have here looks good to me.

Comment: You are using opencv compiled for visual studio 2013 (vc12) and 2015 (vc14). This is an error by itself because you need to link only to one. You however are using mingw. That means you have to compile opencv with mingw, and link to your libraries

Comment: Fuhhhhhg. x64\\ **vc14** \\lib totally missed that. Feel soooo dumb.

Comment: Thank you for finding the problem! So I will compile OpenCV with MinGW and then link it to my libaries agin.

Comment: Yeah, it works! For compiling OpenCV with MinGW, I followed [this](http://eyalarubas.com/opencv-installation-on-windows-netbeans-mingw.html) tutorial. In the compiling process, there were a few compiling errors caused by undefined variables or functions. But after fixing this bugs in the source code, it works!