# cannot open shared object file 'libopencv_shape.so.3.1' in OpenCV

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

So I've just installed OpenCV on my computer and I'm trying to do a quick test to get everything working. My computer runs on Linux Deepin 15. Makes the problem a bit hard to solve as it's not exactly a well known, popular distro.

Anyway, here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    Mat color = imread("lena.jpg");
    Mat gray = imread("lena.jpg", 0);

    imwrite("lenaGray.jpg", gray);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this using the following command in the terminal:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

It compiles seemingly with no error. Creating a 'main' file although the icon in the file manager is not that of an executable file.

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_shape.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do. I really need to get opencv up and running. I've looked on the internet and have found nothing even referencing the 'libopencv_shape.so.3.1' file.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [I just learned over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048991/using-opencv-in-eclipse-getting-started) that open CV now bundles all of their libs in one megalib. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You must to run the following command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
```

It will resolve your problem. This will only work on your current bash instance though. You need to copy this line to your bashrc file (`~/.bashrc`) for future instances